# Navigate new Screen with persist nav bar

Tags: flutter, dart

from cart page i Navigate login page without persist nav page, its okey.

```
 PersistentNavBarNavigator.pushNewScreen(
    context,
    screen: Login(),
    withNavBar: false, // OPTIONAL VALUE. True by default.
    pageTransitionAnimation: PageTransitionAnimation.cupertino,
  );
```

but when login success i want navigate next page from cart page with persist nav bar

```
   PersistentNavBarNavigator.pushNewScreen(
    context,
    screen: Nexpage(),
    withNavBar: true, // OPTIONAL VALUE. True by default.
    pageTransitionAnimation: PageTransitionAnimation.cupertino,
  );
```

but its doesnot work